# Determining the 3rd vertex of an Equilateral and Right angled isoceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am really having problems solving the following problems:

1. If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of the two vertices on the hypotenuse of a right angled isosceles triangle then the coordinates of the 3rd vertex are?
2. Similarly-If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the coordinates of the two vertices of an Equilateral Triangle then the coordinates of the 3rd vertex are?

The answer to 1 and 2 respectively are-

$$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2 \pm(y_1-y_2)}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2 \pm(x_1-x_2)}{2}\right)$$

And

$$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2 \pm\sqrt 3(y_1-y_2)}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2 \pm\sqrt 3(x_1-x_2)}{2}\right)$$

How do I solve this problem?

I tried attempting it by using the fact that the triangle is isosceles and right angled in the first case. So I applied pythagoras theorem but failed to get this answer it was a complicated equation. Secondly I tried multiplying the slopes of the legs of the triangle to get -1 but even this attempt failed.

It was similar with the equilateral triangle problem.

I guess if I understand how to do even one easily the second should bit be difficult.

Please help.

Comment: Do the consecutive + and - stand for plus-minus? And are you familiar with complex numbers?

Comment: Yes they do.. Plus or minus.. Yes i am familiar

Comment: I suggested an edit. Did I screw up anything?

Comment: Just the brackets now it fine.. The whole thing is divided by 2

Comment: CAN this question be done Without Rotation or complex nos using simple pythogoras theorem or distance formula maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the fact that if P(x,y) is the unknown point, then when you apply rotation around that point, the point P1(x1, y1) goes to (gets mapped to) P2(x2,y2). From this you can construct equations and solve them to get the x and y. Just lookup the formulas for rotation in the 2D plane. The rotation angles are nice in both cases: 90 and 60 degrees. If you do this, you should get the answers you have posted here.

Say you rotate the point (x1,y1) around the point (a,b) on an angle of $\theta$.
Then the point (x1,y1) gets mapped to (x2, y2) where:
$x_2 = (x_1-a) * cos(\theta) - (y_1-b) * sin(\theta) + a$
$y_2 = (x_1-a) * sin(\theta) + (y_1-b) * cos(\theta) + b$

In your case you don't know the $a$ and $b$, you want to find them.
The $\theta$ is $\pm \pi/2$ and $\pm \pi/3$ respectively. 
The $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ - these you know.

Here is how one can solve the case: $\pi/3$. You have 3 more cases to solve.
[image]

See also:

[Rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29)
[Rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Comment: The answers you have given isnt correct.. Please read my question and the answer again

Comment: No, thanks. You read, think, and calculate some more. Using my formulas I got your answers using paper and pencil.

Comment: Post the pic of your working then please.

Comment: Posted, you should say thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice.. But what about the plus or minus sign ? And i dont think it will work when the triangle is right angled. Cos theta will be 0...

Comment: It will work too for the right angled triangle, just try it yourself. What about the plus/minus: well, they correspond to your unknown point being "above" or "below" the segment formed by the 2 known points. That's why I said you need to solve 3 more cases for theta: (1) -pi/3, (2) pi/2, (3) -pi/2.

Comment: Peter how did u get this formula -Say you rotate the point (x1,y1) around the point (a,b) on an angle of θ.
Then the point (x1,y1) gets mapped to (x2, y2) where:
x2=(x1−a)∗cos(θ)−(y1−b)∗sin(θ)+a

Comment: Yesterday I took it from the Internet. Also, years ago I studied it in the University.

Comment: For a complex number i understand that one can work it out like that but with vertices? Please give me the link or explanation or best a derivation of this also of this please... If this formula is correct i have understood the whole thing...

Comment: I gave you two links. The formula is correct, otherwise we would have got wrong answers for your 2 examples (with the 60/90 degrees). Here is 1 more link (look at kirchwey's answer): https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100314163944AAIu9xk

Comment: If you take an analytic geometry course, they will prove it for you. It's no big deal, I guess you can find it in almost any textbook on analytic geometry.

Comment: Thank you so much!