# Why are there four solutions to $x^2-2x-8=0$ in $\mathbb{R}$? Or am I wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, factoring, quadratics

It might be a very trivial question to ask but why do we get four different solutions for a quadratic equation using these two methods?

$x^2-2x-8=0$

We see that factors are $(x-4)$ and $(x+2)$ so we get $x=4$ or $- 2$.

Now when we factorise in the following way we get different answers:

$x^2-2x=8$

$x(x-2)=8$ [How can this be!?]

And we get $x=8$ or $x=10$ [How!?]

I am very confused.

Comment: For your second factorization: When you plug in $x = 8$, you get $8(8 - 2) = 8$. Is that really solution to your equation?

Comment: Why are there downvotes? This is easy math for several people but effort has been shown. Downvotes are really unnecessary.

Comment: @crash Agreed, though it's come to be expected, no?

Comment: The question is pretty clear too. It asks whether there's a flaw in the chain of reasoning. In fact there _is_ a flaw, so the answer is to show where the flaw is.

Comment: How stupid of me... Lol....

Comment: @JonathanHebert Unfortunately, yes, that has come to be expected. A small handful of people here hellbent on ruining the site. :/

Comment: Now I did not dowbvote and it is not a big deal, but then that the title is "Flaw in Mathematics??" is, well, maybe a bit over the top.

Comment: To reinforce what quid said, the title "Flaw in Mathematics" is bound to be highly provocative (and negatively received). So a more apropos title would be nice. Nonetheless, kudos for being daring enough to post your question and to ask for feedback. You've certainly gotten quite a bit of it!

Comment: FOR all the people who think answering this question was easy i request you to please please please answer this question in the easiest possible way...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216246/determining-the-3rd-vertex-of-an-equilateral-and-right-angled-isoceles-triangle/1216348?noredirect=1#comment2475059_1216348

Comment: Typically, for example on an exam, when you get what you think is a solution to a quadratic equation, it is easy to check your result by substitution. Had you done that and had that realization, you might have phrased your question a bit more responsibly - such as "Flaw in my reasoning" rather than as you did.

Comment: See the topic... And read my last comment :)

Comment: Well, crash certainly improved things, yet you might further consider changing "we" to "I"

Comment: Guys forget about this question now please... Answer this one please..http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216246/determining-the-3rd-vertex-of-an-equilateral-and-right-angled-isoceles-triangle/1216348?noredirect=1#comment2475059_1216348

Comment: @Andrew The "royal we" strikes again!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your mistake is to assume that for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$ab=c\quad\implies\quad  a=c\quad\text{or}\quad b=c.\tag{1}$$
This is not true in general.

For example $2\times\frac{1}{2}=1$, but neither $2=1$ nor $\frac{1}{2}=1$.

**Further explanations:** However, $(1)$ *is* true when $c=0$, and this is why when finding the roots of a polynomial we can factor it and use the argument
$$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0\quad\implies\quad x=\alpha\quad\text{or}\quad x=\beta.$$
To prove that if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$, you can argue by contradiction. If both $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, then surely $ab\neq 0$.

Comment: Great answer.. @Spenser please answer this question also in the easiest possible way...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216246/determining-the-3rd-vertex-of-an-equilateral-and-right-angled-isoceles-triangle/1216348?noredirect=1#comment2475059_1216348

Comment: @user166748 You should consider placing a bounty on that question, when possible, if you really want the answer. This isn't the way of going about obtaining one.

Answer (score 7):

Spenser's answer is great because it addresses the *general* issue. Perhaps to add some clarity, let's look at your particular quandary.

You realized that
$$
x^2-2x-8 = 0\Longleftrightarrow (x-4)(x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow x=4,-2.
$$
Okay. That's great. Now we can rearrange, as you did, for the following:
$$
x^2-2x-8=0\Longleftrightarrow x^2-2x=8\Longleftrightarrow x(x-2)=8\Longleftrightarrow x=?
$$
Try plugging in $x=8$ or $x=10$. They do not work. However, plugging in $x=4$ and $x=-2$ works. It's simply *less obvious* that these $x$-values work when you express your quadratic in this way.

Answer (score 4):

You should notice that's only when ab=**0** then a=0 or b=0
but when you have a*b=8 you can't say a=8 or b=8
for instance a could be equal to 4 and b to 2

Comment: It's funny that as a counter-example, you picked the one instance (WLOG) that isn't actually a counter-example.

Comment: Much better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should do a simple sanity check in a case like this. **Plug your answer back into the original equation and make sure it works.** Use a calculator and nothing more complicated:

Your tentative answers $x = 4, -2, 8, 10$ check out  as

$$(4)^2-2\times(4)-8\stackrel{?}{=}0\space \space \checkmark$$
$$(-2)^2-2\times(-2)-8\stackrel{?}{=}0\space \space \checkmark$$
$$(8)^2-2\times(8)-8\stackrel{?}{=}0\space \space  NO!$$
$$(10)^2-2\times(10)-8\stackrel{?}{=}0\space \space NO!$$